# How to revalidate google plus access token at REST side generated from android

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I have a android app which send google plus api access token generated via social sign in to php based REST service. Then I need it to re-validate at php. Now I have different client credentials for android and website for single google app.

PHP Side code is like

```
            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName($config->gAppName);
            $client->setClientId($config->gClientId);
            $client->setClientSecret($config->gClientSecret);
            //$client->setRedirectUri($config->gRequestUri);

            $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

            $attributes = $client->verifyIdToken($data['accessToken'], $config->gClientId)->getAttributes();
            $socialUserId = $attributes["payload"]["sub"];
```

Request at rest side give error **Wrong number of segments in token** . How it can be resolved ?

UPDATE : After checking authenticating via php code I found that Access Token should be a JSON Object instead of a string. Like

```
{"access_token":"[ACCESS_TOKEN_STRING]","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":[TIMESTAMP],"id_token":"ID_TOKEN","created":[TIMESTAMP]}
```

Still don't know, How it should be generated.

Comment: to my knowledge PHP can not use a client id and or refresh token that was generated by an android application.

Comment: @DaImTo, If it is documented somewhere, So I can finalize approach ?

Comment: I think you are talking about this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth to my knowledge it only works with the JavaScript and android libraries probably some google magic

Comment: @DaImTo I did not find any reference Cross Client Auth block. They simple say that no authentication is needed for same token I think

Comment: my point is that I don't think the php client library supports it.  you may want to post on their issue forum.  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client  if you do get it working I would love a sample of it.

Comment: seems absurd to have negative score so i upped it. its a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out online docs, I got another solution. I need to use API url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

This url will validate access token as well as give user id for rematch against user id from android app.